# How to backup seed in lightning and give your channel to watchtower

Tags: lightning-network, seed, mnemonic-seed, lightning-routing

this is followup on question #85475:

I have learned in previous question that there is an automatic refund mechanism in case of force closure of a channel, except for some very rare circumstances. I would like to ask about two of those circumstances:
,

1-how to "back up your channel state" or how to back up your seed in lightning? 
(is "channel state" here a synonym for "seed"?)

And why do people say the "seed" works differently in lightning compared to btc - differently how?
,

2-how can you "give your channel to a **watchtower**" ?  IN practical terms, if you use a current lightning wallet

thanks

Answer (score 1):

For clightning I have created a video that explains how to restore your node with seed and state you can watch it here: https://youtu.be/-S7pQOw36vI

The general idea is that hsm_secret sites your seed in binary and the sqlite3 datebase sites your channel states.

I believe in lnd the process would be similar only that they give you the seed words explicitly instead of hsm_secret. They should also have some database or file in which they site channel state.

As for watchtowers. Currently to the best of my knowledge there are no such services available.

Comment: thx.  @rene-pickhardt - and what about other wallets? what with eclair, how backup their seed?

and  if watchtowers do not exist, why this guy "stefanwouldgo" in this thread referenced to watchtowers? https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/85475/lightning-question-about-force-closures-of-channels-and-its-impact-on-recoveri

Comment: Can't say for eclair but would assume similar to lnd. Stefanwouldgo probably mentioned watchtowers as the entire protocol is build with watching services in mind. So I guess most people expects them to come eventually

Comment: Please read my comments in the other thread!